# How to setup storybook on an existing project

Tags: storybook, angular-storybook

I've tried this. `npx -p @storybook/cli sb init --type angular`, on an existing project but fails with.

And dependancies look like :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.0.2",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.2.6",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^13.0.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "angular2-prettyjson": "^3.0.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^2.1.1",
    "archiver": "^3.1.1",
    "body-scroll-lock": "^2.6.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "firebase": "^7.11.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "localforage": "^1.7.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "marked": "^1.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "open-graph": "^0.2.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "scss": "^0.2.4",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-transformer-keys": "^0.4.1",
    "turndown": "^6.0.0",
    "underscore.string": "^3.3.5",
    "zip-local": "^0.3.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-notes": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/angular": "^5.3.19",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.33",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "codelyzer": "~5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.6.2",
    "tslint": "^6.1.1",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

[image]

I've also tried removing node modules and installing again, it just comes back here.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Angular development, but it seems that there might be a syntax issue in a configuration file. Are you using a yarn workspace by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there are 2 '}'s at the end, is that intentional? if not try removing one of them.

Comment: it might be helpful if you can show the rest of the errors